# Dot.NET Core 5 Routing

Tags: .net, routes

I am trying to route to a page, but it is not working as I anticipated.

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
                             "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("onwhite", 
                               "{ controller=Portfolio}/{action=OnWhite}");
        });
```

I can get to the Default index page just fine, utilizing the root Domain, however if I try to visit https://www.example.com/onwhite, it fails to locate the page.  Consequently, calling https://www.example.com/Portfolio/OnWhite also works just fine.

How do I get what I am looking for in .NET Core 5 if I use the Routing Endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller endpoint mapping needs to be done in order of most specific to least specific.

What's happening here is that the first ('default') route is being matched, and .NET is looking for a class called 'OnwhiteController' - which doesn't exist.  It's not even reaching the 'onwhite' route definition.

What you need is to define a custom pattern - 'onwhite' - and specify which controller and action need to be used to display that page.

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "onwhite", 
         pattern: "onwhite", // this is what matches in the URL
         defaults: new { controller = "Portfolio", action = "OnWhite" }
     );

     endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
         "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

### Separating routes

The `UseEndpoints` method here takes a single parameter `Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder>`.  You could create a static class to hold all your routes like this, which would help keep your Startup.cs file clean:

```cs
public static class Endpoints
{
    public static void Add(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "onwhite", 
            pattern: "onwhite", // this is what matches in the URL
            defaults: new { controller = "Portfolio", action = "OnWhite" }
        );

        // add the rest of your endpoints here

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
}
```

And then you can do this in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(Endpoints.Add);
```

Comment: With your approach, the /onwhite link becomes the default nd is the default landing page.  I am looking for both of the to work, i.e., I want to launch the index page by default and also abel to use /onwhite to navigate to the onwhite page.

Comment: Any joy?  I named the parameters in the edit to make it clear what each does.

Comment: Yes, that edit is working.  Do you know how to create a RouteMap table?  Instead of adding all the remaining routes into the StartUp.cs Configure, I would like to have a specific page that holds them.

Comment: The signature of the `UseEndpoints` method is `Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder>` so the simplest way is probably to create a static class to hold them - I'll update the answer with that too.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank You!